# my template cannot read the property of 'id'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to update a user's information using the event (click) = "editUser (eb_user)" in the template. The attribute 'id' is not read.

Here is the error I receive:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
>           at UsersComponent.push../src/app/component/users/users.component.ts.UsersComponent.editUser
>   (users.component.ts:32)
>           at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (UsersComponent.html:24)
>           at handleEvent (core.js:23107)
>           at callWithDebugContext (core.js:24177)
>           at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:23904)
>           at dispatchEvent (core.js:20556)
>           at core.js:21003
>           at HTMLButtonElement. (platform-browser.js:993)
>           at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:423)
>           at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290)

This is the template:

```html
<table class="table table-striped; mat-elevation-z8" style="width: 100%;">
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Nom</th>
    <th>Prénom</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor = "let user of users">
    <td>{{user.id}}</td>
    <td>{{user.nom}}</td>
    <td>{{user.prenom}}</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="editUser(eb_user)" style="margin-left: 20px;"> Edit</button>|
        </td>
  </tr>
```

Here is the editUser () method:

```js
editUser(user: eb_user){
    this.users = [];
    localStorage.removeItem("editUserId");
    localStorage.setItem("editUserId", user.id.toString());
    this.router.navigate(['edit-user']);
  };
```

I expect the click event normally works

Comment: (click)="editUser(user) change this thing it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Who is `eb_user` from `(click)="editUser(eb_user)"`?

It should be `(click)="editUser(user)"` because you do iterate over `users` with `user` variable in ngFor.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Change to `(click)="editUser(user)` it use user local variable in let

```
<table class="table table-striped; mat-elevation-z8" style="width: 100%;">
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Nom</th>
    <th>Prénom</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor = "let user of users">
    <td>{{user.id}}</td>
    <td>{{user.nom}}</td>
    <td>{{user.prenom}}</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="editUser(user)" style="margin-left: 20px;"> Edit</button>|
        </td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change function calling like follows in Html

```
<td><button (click)="editUser(user)" style="margin-left: 20px;"> Edit</button>|      </td>
```

You need to pass `user` item not `eb_user` Model

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is pass the user object and access the id in ts or you can also pass the id directly from html here is an example

```
// here we are passing user object
<tr *ngFor = "let user of users">
   <td><button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="editUser(user)" style="margin-left: 20px;"> Edit</button></td> 
</tr>

// here we are passing user.id to ts
<tr *ngFor = "let user of users">
  <td><button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="editUser(user.id)" style="margin-left: 20px;"> Edit</button></td> 
</tr>
```